# Doubt in necklace proof of Fermat's little theorem

Tags: combinatorics

The following image is the necklace proof of Fermat's little theorem taken from https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Fermat%27s_Little_Theorem#Proof_3_.28Combinatorics.29

My understanding of this proof is is that there is no need for p to be a prime number. And that for all p, where p is any positive integer, the proof given below should hold. Where am I being wrong ?

[image]

P.S: Fermat's little theorem states that if p is a prime number, then for any integer a, the number (a^p − a) is an integer multiple of p.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536229/why-need-prime-number-in-fermats-little-theorem/2536243#2536243

Answer (score 1):

If $p=4$ you can consider the alternating black and white necklace. It only produces two different neclaces when you rotate.

You need $p$ to be prime so that every necklace that isn't all the same color yields $p$ different ones when you consider the $p$ rotations.

Comment: How do you know that if and only if p is a prime number then "every necklace that isn't all the same color yields p different ones when you consider the p rotations".

Comment: Because the number of different necklaces has to be a divisor of $p$

Comment: "Because the number of different necklaces has to be a divisor of p."  How does this statement prove that p is a prime number ?

Comment: Oh, for the other direction of the implication you can take a coloring that repeates every $d$ colors where $d$ is a direction of $p$.